# How to remove extra space from the bottom of Scrollview

Tags: android

How to remove extra space from the bottom of Scrollview. Below is the XML layout where I am including two external layouts. Have refered many solutions but none of them worked for me.

[image]

```
     <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sc"

        android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linprodetaill"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bt"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <include
                android:id="@+id/l1"
                layout="@layout/productexpand_items" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/l3"
                layout="@layout/dynamic_view"

                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: You have a margin bottom inside your scrollView

Answer (score 0):

Remove  **`android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"`** from your **`ScrollView`**

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/sc"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linprodetaill"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <include
            android:id="@+id/l1"
            layout="@layout/productexpand_items" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/l3"
            layout="@layout/dynamic_view"

            />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: There are two buttons above which I need this scroll so given margin

Comment: send screen shoot

Comment: @AshutoshTripathi Please check the screen shot link

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your xml

```
 android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
```

it will remove the extra space , u can set 10dp just to give enough spacing

Answer (score 0):

nest your `scrollView` and the other layouts in a `Relative layout`.
and then use the `layout_below` attribute to align the layouts below your scrollView.
and make sure to inclue `layout_alignParentTop="true"` in your scrollView's xml and remove the bottom margin of your scrollView.

now when the bottom layouts have their visibility value changed to `Visible` or `Gone`, scrollView will fill the parent or leave room for them,